# Apply CSS class conditionally to Angular component host

Tags: html, css, angular, angular9

I have an angular component with boolean input parameters. Based on whether they are true or false, I want to add a CSS class to the host. I know I can wrap my entire component in a div and use ngClass. But what if I don't want to add an extra div in my template? I just want the host to have those classes conditionally. Is that possible?
Say this is my component:

```
 export class AssetDetailsComponent {
  @Input isSomethingTrue = true;
  @Input isThisAlsoTrue = true;

  constructor() {}
}
```

And this is what the template looks like:

```
<h1> Page heading </h2>
<p> Details </p>
```

Now based on the value of `isSomethingTrue` and `isThisAlsoTrue`, I want to apply 2 different CSS classes or styles to the host (to add some margin-top). How do I do that in the component?

Comment: it is not necessary for ngClass to use in a div tag, you can also use ngClass in other tags, such as in your case `h1` or `p`. you can add conditional class in these tags too. in this way you don't need any extra div to wrap your component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine `@HostBinding` with an `@Input` property to apply a class conditionally to the component host, based on the property value. In the code below, classes `class1` and `class2` are applied to the host element depending on `condition1` and `condition2` respectively:

```js
@HostBinding("class.class1") @Input() condition1: boolean;
@HostBinding("class.class2") @Input() condition2: boolean;
```

The CSS styles can be defined as follows:

```css
:host.class1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
:host.class2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bjhvj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) for a demo.

---

An alternative syntax is to set the host class bindings in the component metadata:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    "[class.class1]": "condition1",
    "[class.class2]": "condition2"
  }
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() condition1: boolean;
  @Input() condition2: boolean;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kndddj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) for a demo.